# Screenshot application that creates a file on your desktop( for windows )

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, screenshot

On a mac, when you take a screenshot the OS creates a file with it on the desktop.

Is there such an alternative for Windows so when I use the "Print Screen" key or a key combination it lets me take the screenshot and save a .jpg (or any kind of image file) to my computer (ideally desktop).

Comment: ShareX http://code.google.com/p/sharex/downloads/list

Comment: As an FYI, if you ever do make the leap to Win8, Windows key + PrtScr will save a screenshot in your Pictures/Screenshots directory.

Comment: I like Greenshot for screenshots.

Comment: Your question was off topic, I made some edits to make it on topic. If you don't like them you can roll the changes back

Answer (score 2):

All the tools I have used are a little more complex than it sounds like you want.  When ever I have a question like this I start with sourceforge.  Here is an example of something that sounds like it is headed in the right direction.

http://lightscreen.sourceforge.net/

Light, configurable, quick saves, and free in both senses.  But there are a ton of them at sourceforge just by searching on screenshot and sorting by most popular will give you some great choices.

Comment: My favorite - I prefer date and time format `yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss`. [Lightscreen help](https://lightscreen.com.ar/help#date/time/expressions). Select (date) and specify date pattern in additional settings.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert suggested above, try [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org):

Configurable keyboard shortcuts:
[image: 1]

Configurable storage location, file naming pattern and image format:
[image: 2]

Configurable destination:
[image: 3]

and much more!